# How to filter taxonomy args with register_taxonomy_args WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy, wordpress-hook

I am trying to filter the taxonomy args on a selection of custom taxonomies with the **register_taxonomy_args** filter hook. However when doing so I am getting quite a lot of error messages.

**To list a few:**

Warning: Missing argument 2 for edit_bb_taxonomy_args() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/broadbean/wp-content/themes/scratch/functions.php on line 278

Warning: Missing argument 3 for edit_bb_taxonomy_args() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/broadbean/wp-content/themes/scratch/functions.php on line 278

Notice: Undefined variable: taxonomy in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/broadbean/wp-content/themes/scratch/functions.php on line 280

Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/broadbean/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 379

Notice: Undefined index: rewrite in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/broadbean/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 398

**My filter function**

```
<?php
function edit_bb_taxonomy_args( $args, $taxonomy, $object_type ) {

    $taxonomies = array( 'wpbb_job_type', 'wpbb_job_location', 'wpbb_job_industry', 'wpbb_job_skill' );

    if ( in_array( $taxonomy, $taxonomies ) ) {
        $args = array(
            'with_front' => false
        );
        return $args;
    }
}
add_filter('register_taxonomy_args', 'edit_bb_taxonomy_args' );
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No worries I have sorted it now.

If you're interested solution is below...

```
<?php
function my_edit_bb_taxonomy_args( $args, $taxonomy, $object_type ) {

    $taxonomies = array( 'wpbb_job_type', 'wpbb_job_location', 'wpbb_job_industry', 'wpbb_job_skill' );
    if ( in_array( $taxonomy, $taxonomies ) ) {
        /* alter the rewrite with front arg */
        $args[ 'rewrite' ][ 'with_front' ] = false;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'my_edit_bb_taxonomy_args', 10, 3 );
?>
```

Comment: Hi There, I know this is a fairly old post but I am going through the exact same process with very little luck...